# Rails app not working in production environment on local machin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

When in development env it is working fine, but when I run the app in production evn, it says **We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.**

The production log says:

```
I, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.667458 #31504]  INFO -- : [74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-21 19:25:25 +0530
I, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.668742 #31504]  INFO -- : [74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631] Processing by DashboardController#home as HTML
I, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.670973 #31504]  INFO -- : [74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]   Rendering dashboard/home.html.haml within layouts/application
I, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.671255 #31504]  INFO -- : [74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]   Rendered dashboard/home.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 15)
I, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.672210 #31504]  INFO -- : [74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (Allocations: 1237)
F, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.673501 #31504] FATAL -- : [74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]   
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /home/zamir/rails_studio/sunrise/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-fafdbfed632f089e407b.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-fafdbfed632f089e407b.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-fafdbfed632f089e407b.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-fafdbfed632f089e407b.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
):
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]      6:       = controller.page_title
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]      7:     = csrf_meta_tags
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]      8:     = csp_meta_tag
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]      9:     = stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]     10:     = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]     11:   %body
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]     12:     .container-fluid
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631]   
[74b45073-2b93-4d6e-8d02-346cf6c72631] app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:9
I, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.988388 #31504]  INFO -- : [6a573ad4-9775-4565-8f2e-e32395e409cd] Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-21 19:25:25 +0530
F, [2020-04-21T19:25:25.989343 #31504] FATAL -- : [6a573ad4-9775-4565-8f2e-e32395e409cd]   
[6a573ad4-9775-4565-8f2e-e32395e409cd] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is in the `production.rb` configuration file: you should allow Puma to serve static files.

In production servers, static files are usually served by Nginx, but that's not the case if you run Puma on your local machine.

In order to do so, in your `production.rb` set this value to true (or create an `ENV` variable named `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES`):

> config.public_file_server.enabled = true

Answer (score 2):

Add gem `rails_12factor` to your Gemfile. This will add error logging and the ability for your app to serve static assets.

Remember to clobber your assets

`RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:clobber
 RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

In config/webpacker.yml make extract_css option true for production:

```
extract_css: true
```

Then run the following command before starting the server in production mode:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```